# Thread to initiate thread creation in a service

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I want to create an executor with fixed pool of 3 threads inside a service.

Those 3 threads will do some work according to data on my SQLite DB.

Is there a way to tell the threads to "call" some method on the service that will tell him, "a thread is done, you can now pull the data from the DB and start a new thread"

That way I can manipulate the DB and the next threads will act accordingly.

All I managed to do is to fill up the queue with all the data I have on my DB, and that way it wont react to changes on the DB cause I already pulled all the data

EDIT: some code for better understanding

```
public class MediaDownloadService extends Service {
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2,3,3000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    //initiale start of new threads (first run)
}

public void startNewThread(){
    if(helper.requestsExists()){
        Map<Integer,String> requestMap = helper.getRequestsToExcute(0);
        Set<Integer> keySet = requestMap.keySet();
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = keySet.iterator();
        executor.submit(new MyThread(file, getApplicationContext(), iteratorNext), 1);
    }else{
        executor.shutdown();
        this.stopSelf();
    }
}
```

and The thread himself:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

private File _file;
private Context context;
private DBHelper helper;
private int requestId;

public MyThread(File file, Context context, int requestId) {
    this._file = file;
    this.context = context;
    this.requestId = requestId;
}

@Override
public void run() {
        // Thread work here

        helper.deleteRequest(requestId);// remove from db to prevent infinite loop

        // THIS IS THE QUESTION
        MediaDownloadService.startNewThread();// ??? can it be done

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Callable try", post.toString());

    }
}
```

of course I dont want it to be static, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Edited the question with some code for better understanding, I thought about the future objec like you mention, but the logic of it keeps letting me down, Ill have to do a while(future.get()) and wait until it returns an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I managed to find a solution:

First I learned how to bind a service with IBinder through here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0c4jRCm353c

So my service will now look like this:

```
public class MediaDownloadService extends Service {

private DBHelper helper;
private ExecutorService executor;
private final IBinder sharonsBinder = new MyLocalBinder();
File file;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return sharonsBinder;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    helper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2,3,3000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    Log.e("requestsExists", helper.requestsExists() + "");
   if(helper.requestsExists()){
        // map of the index of the request and the string of the absolute path of the request
        Map<Integer,String> requestMap = helper.getRequestsToExcute(3);
        Set<Integer> keySet = requestMap.keySet();
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = keySet.iterator();
        Log.e("MAP",requestMap.toString());
        //checks if the DB requests exists
        if(!requestMap.isEmpty()){
            //execute them and delete the DB entry
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                int iteratorNext = iterator.next();
                Log.e("ITREATOR", iteratorNext + "");
                file = new File(requestMap.get(iteratorNext));
                Log.e("file", file.toString());
                Log.e("thread Opened", "Thread"+iteratorNext);
                executor.submit(new MyTask(file, getApplicationContext(), iteratorNext), 1);
                helper.requestTaken(iteratorNext);
            }
        }
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void startNewTask(){
    if(helper.requestsExists()){
        Map<Integer,String> requestMap = helper.getRequestsToExcute(1);
        Set<Integer> keySet = requestMap.keySet();
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = keySet.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
                int iteratorNext = iterator.next();
                file = new File(requestMap.get(iteratorNext));
                Log.e("file", file.toString());
                Log.e("thread Opened", "Thread"+iteratorNext);
                executor.submit(new MyTask(file, getApplicationContext(), iteratorNext), 1);
                helper.requestTaken(iteratorNext);
            }
    }else{
        executor.shutdown();
        this.stopSelf();
    }
}
 public class MyLocalBinder extends Binder{
    MediaDownloadService getService(){
        return MediaDownloadService.this;
    }
}
```

Now I bind my task to the service so it will be able to call the startNewTask() method like this:

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {

private File _file;
private Context context;
private DBHelper helper;
private int requestId;
private MediaDownloadService sharonsService;
boolean isBound = false;

public MyTask(File file, Context context, int requestId) {
    this._file = file;
    this.context = context;
    this.requestId = requestId;

}

@Override
public void run() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,MediaDownloadService.class);
    context.bindService(intent,sharonsConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        // some work here
        sharonsService.startNewTask();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Callable try", post.toString());

    }
}

private ServiceConnection sharonsConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
       MyLocalBinder binder = (MyLocalBinder) service;
        sharonsService = binder.getService();
        isBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        isBound = false;
    }
};
```

Works fine, the thread is opened only when the task is done

Hope it'll help people with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misconceptions here: `Executor.submit()` does not accept a `Thread`, but a `Runnable`. It will put that `Runnable` into a queue and possibly (after some time) assign a thread to perform the actions specified by that runnable. The whole executor exists so that you do not have to do the thread creation, management and task scheduling yourself.

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` thus already implements the queueing funtionality you are trying to implement. Thus one solution is thus to simply submit all tasks to the executor as they come in. The executor will queue them and schedule them to available threads.

Also note that there's [`AsyncTask.execureOnExecutor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) which also gives you the possibility to have `onPostExecute()` running on the main thread.

And please, rename `MyThread` and `startNewThread()` to something else. The former is not a thread, but only a task and the latter only submits work to the executor.